# JQuery Pagination StartPage - unable to assign startpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pagination

I am working with JQuery Pagination in an ASP.Net application.  If I set the start page with a number like the codeblock below I get the right start page.

```
$('#table_3_Pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: $('#hidUnassignedNoPages').val(),
        visiblePages: 7,
        startPage: 3,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
            //__doPostBack('getPage', page)
        }
    });
```

As you can see I am able to assign the correct number of pages, but when I try to get to take the value dynamically from my hidden field like I am in hidUnassignedNoPages then it throws me an error

> Start Page option is incorrect

```
$('#table_3_Pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: $('#hidUnassignedNoPages').val(),
            visiblePages: 7,
            startPage: $('#hidUnassignedNoPages').val(),
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
                //__doPostBack('getPage', page)
            }
        });
```

If I write the value to the console or to an alert message then I get the correct value that is being set.

I am using the library from here http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/

When in the code and looking at the values being passed through in

```
 if (this.options.startPage < 1 || this.options.startPage > this.options.totalPages) {
        throw new Error('Start page option is incorrect');
    }
```

startPage has the right value

I would be grateful if anyone could let me know where I am going wrong on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the value of startPage is a string but not integer.
You can try to parse the string to integer before the condition check.

Comment: getting the text value passed through nothing

Comment: the library you used will not parse startPage you passed, add the parseInt logic in the source code of the library.

Comment: when I give it a fixed number it gives me the right selected page

Comment: yes, fixed number will pass a number but val() will pass a string. You can check Line 21 and 25 of the source code jquery.twbsPagination.js. The library parse the totalpages to integer but not for startPage, it is a potential  bug of the library.

Comment: I see what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

You need verify if *totalPages* is higher than zero, this plugin **not** supported *totalPages* zero and negative *startPage*.

One sugestion is: set the *totalPages* with one case be zero.